# Interactive tree/hierarchical diagramming plug-in for jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, mindmapping, graph-drawing

For a project that I'm working on we need the ability for the user to create an interactive tree/hierarchical diagram. Similar to creating a mindmap but with a top-down orientation.

I've evaluated the various tools but none seem to fit the bill:

- arbor.js: Only for plotting graphs and not for in-place editing/creation
- [JavaScript Infovis Toolkit](http://philogb.github.io/jit/): Neat but good for data in JSON format and not for in-place editing
- Raphael.js: same as above
- [Mindmup](http://www.mindmup.com/): Opensource, almost does what we want, but no API documentation. Must rummage through large JS files to find how to work with simple things like load/save JSON etc.,

Is there ANY jQuery plugin or tool that can be used for creating tree diagrams in an interactive fashion or are we restricted to creating this layer "on top of" the rendering/visualization libraries?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying [dagre](https://github.com/cpettitt/dagre) along with [D3](http://d3js.org/) for the visualization. It's not so much jQuery specific, it's plain old JS. The only thing is you won't get interaction built-in. For hierarchical layout with interaction you're looking at something like [mxGraph](http://www.jgraph.com), but that's a whole different price ballpark.